# Upload string contents into google doc

Tags: c#, .net, google-docs, google-docs-api

I wanna know if I can create a doc on google docs without uploading document..
I just want to pass the value of a textbox from my c# windows application and store it onto the google docs server..
I don't want to create any intermediate file to upload on google docs.. I'm storing the textbox data in ms access database and I want it to be saved at google docs too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following code:

```
DocumentsService service = new DocumentsService("MyApp");

// TODO: Authorize the service object

Stream stream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes("This is the document content"));

DocumentEntry entry = service.Insert(new Uri(DocumentsListQuery.documentsBaseUri), stream, "text/plain", "Document title") as DocumentEntry;
```

Comment: I'm using 3.0 version so I didn't used client library..
Do I have to use client library foruploading???

Comment: The .NET client library supports version 3.0 of the API, so you can use it too.

Comment: ohk.. I thot with 3.0 we don't have to use Client libraries any more.. guess I was wrong..

So now what I need to do is.. after sending http request on the resumable-create-media link  (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#uploading_a_new_document_or_file_with_both_metadata_and_content) I should send data using above code??

Comment: I'm not able to understand it fully yet..
Can you please explain the whole creating process to me with the context of this - https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#uploading_a_new_document_or_file_with_both_metadata_and_content

to create doc I need to send an http request to resumable-create-media link then when and how should I send my string contents exactly??

and in POST request what should be the content type and lenght in this case??

Comment: The code above doesn't use resumable upload, the .NET examples for resumable upload will be added to the docs soon.

Comment: so what do you suggest me to do now?
Large part of my app is coded using 3.0 API..
and I have this school project due next week..

Comment: I mean can I interchange between API versions in the app.. As for authentication and retreiving docs ID, list etc.. I'm using 3.0 version..

Comment: If you only need to create a file with a text content, then you can use the code above. It is valid in version 3.0 of the API. In general, you should use resumable upload, though.

Comment: Can u provide documentation link for above code too??
As I'll need to update the entry too..

Comment: That code is not covered in the docs, I wrote it to answer your question

Comment: ohk.. Now for using 2.0 protocol will I have to authenticate also using client library as of now m not using any client library and was authenticating by sending post request and receiving auth code (among other things) in response..

Comment: Hi, I'm able to create new document with this code now.. but what about when I want to edit the content of the already created doc file??
I tried using above code and replacing "DocumentsListQuery.documentsBaseUri" with edit-media link of the document but it didnt worked and threw exception.. what m i doing wrong here?